# REST Resource Testing

Tags: testing, rest

I want to test a REST Resource:

```
 @GET
@Path("/{dbName}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getRequest(@PathParam("dbName") String dbName)
        throws JSONException  {
```

}

I want to do this :

```
assert(someExpectedOutput,getRequest())
```

Now How the PAth will be set for @Path annotation ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to call `getRequest` directly for testing, as a Java method, go right ahead and pass it a single string:

```
assertEquals(someExpectedOutput, getRequest("someMockDbName"));
```

It is after all, just a Java method with one string parameter.

The JAX-RS annotations only kick in when you are running a server, in which case the framework will match the path parameter to your Java parameter `dbname`.  I assume for testing you are just going to use mock objects, so no worries.  Pass whatever string you like.

Now if you are going to test within a server (more like an integration test), consider something like Jetty for the webserver and HSQLDB or Derby for a database.  That kind of testing is much more involved.

Comment: This may be helpful when doing integration testing: http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/13/integration-testing-a-rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

Found Jersey framework for Testing (com.sun.jersey.test.framework) that is useful too. or do it the normal junit way as above.